# JS code highlighting regex

Tags: javascript, regex, syntax-highlighting

I'm a beginner in regex.

I've been trying on regex101 trying to figure out a way to capture the **variable identifiers in declarations**. Basically the `x` in `var x = 1;` but not `x = x + 1`.

I'm working with PrismJS to try to highlight my code and it **doesn't** support non-capturing `(?:)` and **it captures every partial matches** but it has an option to ignore the first brackets to imitate a "look-behind" function.

I test with the following text:

```
var a = 1,
    b=2,
    c = 3;
var d = 5;
var x, y = 3,
z;

var x = 1,
    z = 1.23E4, //comment
    w = +Infinity,
    u = NaN,
    t = 0x6F, //hexidecimal
    r = 0o37; //octadecimal
```

This far, I can only figure out a trick regex:

```
/(var *| *,\n* *)(\w+)(?= *=| *,| *;)/g
// not captured    ^   not captured
//             captured
```

**The first brackets are ignored and not captured to imitate lookbehind.** I can't make it work with `var` after `|` in the first brackets.

But of course, it will capture this as well which I don't want:

```
,
a =
```

Please help. There are so many limitations or maybe it's just me being too stupid, I can't construct a regex that works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, after a couple hours tinkering, here's a preliminary version!

The regex is `/(var\s*|(?!^),\s*|(?!^),\s*\/\/ *.*?\n\s*)(\w+)/gm`.

Explanation:

```
(
    var\s*                   // Matches "var" + whitespace (always a declaration)
  | (?!^),\s*                // Matches comma + whitespace
  | (?!^),\s*\/\/ *.*?\n\s*  // Matches comma + // comment + newline(s)
)
(\w+)                        // The identifier itself
```

By the way, this works in for loops, etc as well thanks to case 1 with `var`.

Case 3 is the funky one; it doesn't work for all cases but captures quite a lot of them. It looks for an inline comment following a comma (important) with whitespace around it.

Here's a demo below, where we highlight the variable names. Note that this doesn't capture the whole assignment, but you could add some optional stuff to highlight the whole thing or just the value as opposed to just the identifier.

```js
function highlight (src) {
    var regex = /(var\s*|(?!^),\s*|(?!^),\s*\/\/ *.*?\n\s*)(\w+)/gm;
    return src.replace(regex, "$1<span class='hl'>$2</span>");
}

window.onload = function () {
    var src = document.querySelector("pre").textContent;
    document.querySelector("pre").innerHTML = highlight(src);
};
```

```css
body {
    line-height: 20px;
}
.hl {
    background: rgba(90, 255, 90, 0.2);
    border-radius: 3px;
    padding: 0 3px;
    border: 1px solid #444;
    cursor: default;
}
.hl:hover {
    background: rgba(90, 255, 90, 0.7);
}
```

```html
<pre>
// everything below should highlight
var a = 1,
    b = 2,
    c = 3;
var d = 5;
var x, y = 3,
z;

z; // this shouldn't highlight

var me = 9, z3 = 10; // these two should highlight

x = x + 1; // this shouldn't

for (var i = 0; i < 5) {} // `i` here should highlight

// these should highlight
var x,y;
var m=19, zzz=12;

// this shouldn't
zzz = 15;

// and all of these should highlight.
var x = 1,
    z = 1.23E4, //comment
    someName = +Infinity,
    u = NaN,
    t = 0x6F, //hexidecimal
    r = 0o37; //octadecimal

// these should both highlight                      
var x, // variable
    y;

// these should be highlighted too
var x, //variable
y;

// and this shouldn't
,
a = 4;
</pre>
```

Comment: I just found a bug `var x, //variable [newline] y;` It captures `iable` as an identifier so the whitespace after `var` should be `var\s+` and not `*`

Comment: No it doesn't...updated with that example. But, I did fix an issue with inline comments that start with a space, like `// comment` as opposed to `//comment`.

Comment: @DanielCheung: Okay, I figured out the problem, and it's fixed in the answer now. :)

Comment: Remember that this is a preliminary version. We're not here to write an entire parser for you. This is to get you started...I'm sure you can manipulate it to fit your needs.

Comment: but it did select `, [newline] a` without `var` prior it. I'm not complaining this already beautiful work. I guess I will look for a work around?

Comment: Hmm...you did require that in the question. I will work on this more and see if that can be done. You absolutely can't use negative lookahead?

Comment: I think I can, just not `(?:)` non-capture groups. But now I first search for the `/var ([\w\W]*?);/` from vks's answer, then use your regex to search within.

Comment: You can just include `(?!^)` before the `,` in cases 2 and 3. Basically, make sure the comma isn't the first character on the line. Also not perfect, but its a start.

Comment: I agree! Good luck with whatever this is for -- looks like a big project! :)